# how to select multiple columns within subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to define query something like this:

`select sum(column) from table1 where id in(select column1, column2 from  table2);`

How can I do this?

**Update::**

table1(id | base_p_id  | additional_p_id)

```
     1|    2    | 4

     2|    2    | 3
```

table2(id | desc | cost)

```
   2  |   -     |1200

   4  |  -      |400
```

Now base_p_id  & additional_p_id is fk of table2 , and I want to take the sum of the cost

like

**select sum(cost) from table2 where id in(select base_p_id ,additional_p_id) from table1 where id=1);**

-Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use UNION :

```
SELECT
    sum(column)
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT col1 FROM table2 UNION SELECT col2 FROM table 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a join. This will also be much faster than using `IN` with a sub-query:

```
select sum(table1.column) 
from table1 
inner join table2 on table2.column1 = table1.id or table2.column2 = table1.id
```